# Unable to use concat in stripped down version of ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, ffprobe, mobile-ffmpeg, android-ffprobe

I have compiled ffmpeg for my android app to have only essential components. I have enabled following components.

```
--disable-everything \
--enable-demuxer=concat \
--enable-muxer=concat,mp4 \
--enable-protocol=file,subfile \
--enable-filter=amix,adelay,volume \
```

But when I am trying to concatenate mp4 files using following command

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

I am receiving following error

```
[concat @ 0x7bd7d14400] Impossible to open 'file1.mp4'
files.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Here is complete ffmpeg output for reference

```
    Command execution failed with rc=1 and the output below.
Command execution failed ffmpeg version v4.3-dev-2955 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
      built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
      configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/home/amit/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/amit/work/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --cc=aarch64-linux-android21-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android21-clang++ --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --enable-debug --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --d  libavutil      56. 42.102 / 56. 42.102
      libavcodec     58. 78.102 / 58. 78.102
      libavformat    58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100
      libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
      libavfilter     7. 77.101 /  7. 77.101
      libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
      libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
    [concat @ 0x7bd7d14400] Impossible to open 'absolute path here/1.mp4'
    absolute path here/files.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
Command execution 7
```

Exact same command works when I compile complete ffmpeg. What components I might be missing for getting this error? Help is appreciated.

Comment: You need a demuxer and/or a parser to read your input files. Your configure script doesn't include anything about them.

Comment: Thanks @taner, I got it working after some trial and errors.

Comment: Since you got it working consider adding an answer.